# How to solve this integral equation?

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I am trying to solve for x the integral equation  :

```
a Integrate[Exp[-s^2]/(s - c x)^2, {s,-Infinity, Infinity}] + 
b Integrate[Exp[-s^2]/(s - d x)^2, {s,-Infinity, Infinity}] = 1
```

where a, b, c and d are numerical values. I have tried **`NIntegrate`**  and some iteration but didn't get me too far... can anyone help me with a better idea?

Comment: Could you share the numerical values of a, b, c and d? That may help.

Comment: yes:a=1.5, b=2, c=0.8, d=1

Comment: The problem I think is that you have a pole, when `s=c x` even though `x` is unknown, it has to be between `-Infinity` and `+infinity`m right? So somewhere along the real line, is a pole. So does not converge

Comment: therefore it is not possible to have a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help:-

```
eqn = a Integrate[Exp[-s^2]/(s - c x)^2, {s, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> Im[c x] != 0] + 
   b Integrate[Exp[-s^2]/(s - d x)^2, {s, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
     Assumptions -> Im[d x] != 0];

a = 1.5; b = 2; c = 0.8; d = 1;

Plot[eqn, {x, -1000, 1000}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please, if x=m+In, how to find  m=Re[x] and n=Im[x]

Comment: Many tanks Chris